# jquery .on function with dynamic content not working in ie9

Tags: jquery, events, internet-explorer-9, handler

I have a select list in a php generated page into which I am loading dynamic  content several times during the page being shown. Each of these option lines should act as a link; therefore I connect a 'click' handler on the select element with a filter to select its option elements. To start with, this is the html I'm using:

```
<select name="suggestions" id="suggestions" size="3">';
</select>';
```

Afterwards I fill in some options as follows:

```
<option value="NextPage.php?id=1">Doe, John</option>
```

The accompanying javascript is the following:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
...
$("#suggestions").on('click', 'option', selectItem);
});

// receiving the list of options
function receiveList(data) {
  $('#suggestions').html(data);
  $('#suggestions').css('display', 'inline');
}

// The click handler for the options
function selectItem(e) {
  var txt = this.value;
  alert('Selected ' + txt);
  window.open(txt);  // or window.location.href = txt;
}
```

This javascript works perfectly in Firefox and in Opera; in IE9, when clicking a line in the selector, the selected line turns blue but no action is taken, and no alert pops up (i.e. selectItem isn't executed).

I'm using jquery-1.8.2.min.js, and the first line of the page is "!doctype html"

Any suggestions how to circumvent this problem?

Comment: the click-event for an `<option/>` doesn't fire in IE, use the change-event of the select instead

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `change` event of the `select`, not `click` on the `option`. Try this:

```
$("#suggestions").on('change', selectItem);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion but it changes things in the wrong way: Neither Firefox nor IE work with this variant. Sorry...

Comment: I also tried to apply the change event both to option and to select: The latter still works in Firefox but not in IE, the former doesn't work for either browser. Sorry...

Comment: Aha! I see now some more effects: Apparently the change event is working but only if I select any line in the selector except the first! But what if I "desperately" want to select that one? Can I set the selected value to 0 or -1 before letting the user select?

Comment: There is an easy but slightly stupid way to overcome the problem: Use the very first option as a kind of title or explanation to the dropdown: "Please select" or similar. This first option is of course selected but there is no use for the user to select it, hence she will select something different and thus trigger the change event.

Comment: @DieterProfos that's not a stupid way to overcome the problem - that's how `select` elements should work